# Maven return artifact hash from Nexus when deploying

Tags: git, maven, tags, commit, nexus

i'm very new(ish) to Maven and Nexus, and am stuck on a problem on linking Github Commits to Nexus artefacts.

I need to be able to map the Branch Name or Commit ID to the specific artefact built in Nexus, as I want to be able to pull down specific packages for specific branches on code repositories. we are using Jenkins as our CI tool.

My current thoughts are; once Maven deploys the artefact to Nexus, we can then tag the Git Commit with the hash of the deployed artefact. Then by querying the Nexus API using the hash and project name, we can get the version of the artefact and grab it by curl requests.

I have many question marks about the approach, but the biggest one right now is:

**Is it possible to 'return' the hash when using Maven to build and deploy artefacts to Nexus. 'Returning' just being the ability to get it somehow and use it in a curl request later on in the build process.**

Does this approach to map Github commits to artefacts make sense?

And if so, does anyone have any ideas around the hash problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first question you have to answer is whether you're deploying SNAPSHOT or a release version. If you're deploying a release version then the easiest thing to do is to tag your repo with the version that you're deploying. If you're using maven versioning:

```
<version>${revision}${sha1}${changelist}</version>
```

Then you could deploy and tag by doing something like:

```
export version=4.23.1.00
mvn deploy -Drevision=$version
git tag $version
git push origin $version
```

If you're using SNAPSHOTs then it depends on on your CI setup but latest SNAPSHOT on Nexus should refer to the latest commit on a given branch. One thing that we do is generate different artifact id for each branch. (This is actually very important as you don't want to generate SNAPSHOTs in the same Nexus artifact from different branches.)